# provisioning hosted solution for SMEs on azure

Tags: azure, instance, clients

i intend to build software for SMEs on the azure platform that can be provisioned for different clients..what i mean is, once the client signs up, a new instance is automatically created for them on the azure platform.

Does anyone have any experience with building such solutions or are their any commercial packages like that available?

thanks

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you're planning to have a single-tenant system, where each instance is slightly different then others and is customized for each client slightly differently. If this is the case, Azure in general will not be a great platform for you. It thrives on providing a dynamic quantity of exactly-alike instances. Furthermore, having one instance per client is a bad idead, as instances are slightly volatile. MS may choose to bring one down for an upgrade, or instance may simply crash, and SLA is only inforced when 2+ instances are running.

I'd like to suggest that you consider multi-tenant environment, where your system shards itself virtually via database/architecture/etc. Do not tie instances to quantity of clients, but to actual load.

Now, if you want to spin up exactly same instances when new clients sign up, check out dynamic scaling service for Azure called AzureWatch @ http://www.paraleap.com - its main premise to scale your instances to load, but with a few simple queue/table inserts it can programmatically scale you up or down. Contact me there if you think this will work for you, and ill be glad to explain how this can be done